# Blue Border around asp link button

Tags: asp.net, css, asplinkbutton

I have 2 asp linkbuttons which encompass img tags within themselves.
The markup is as below:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="Default" runat="server" OnClick="CallDefaultFunction" OnClientClick="Default();">
<img style="border:none;"  src="../Images/BtnSetDefault.png" alt="" id="imgdefault" onmouseover="this.src='../Images/BtnSetDefaultHOVER.png'" onmouseout="this.src='../Images/BtnSetDefault.png'" /> 
</asp:LinkButton>
<asp:LinkButton ID="Delete" runat="server" OnClick="CallDeleteFunction" OnClientClick="return ConfirmOnDelete();">
<img style="border:none;" src="../Images/BtnDelete.png" alt="" id="imgdelete" onmouseover="this.src='../Images/BtnDeleteHOVER.png'" onmouseout="this.src='../Images/BtnDelete.png'" />
</asp:LinkButton>
```

And below is the screenshot as to what it appears in IE 10. I get a very small and tiny blue segment between the link buttons (which is borderd by red box). Need to remove that, tried using Text-decoration:none for linkbutton, but it did not work.

![image]http://postimg.org/image/se162y6z5/

Any help will be appreciated.

Regards
Anurag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

write this `a link tag` `comming` `blue line;` so please use below in your css `style sheet.`

```
a{
    text-decoration:none;
}

img{
    border:none;
}
```

Comment: yes using both together works, which I was not using earlier..thanks

Comment: @Anurag Please my answer is right just give 1 vote up. thanks

Comment: @ fags it says an error has occurred, please retry..will do after some time..thanks